# JS: Do different things depending on if value is null

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<script>
function myGender() {
  if (document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value==null) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Please select your gender";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
      <label for="gender"> Gender: </label> <br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="man"> man<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="woman" >woman<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" >Other<br>
      <button onclick="myGender()">What am I?</button>
     <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vykptm5x/

I want it to say if I have no gender selected, and I dont want to make it checked by default.
It still says in console that it is null, but I have there if statement.

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if

`document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked')`

is `null`, not if its value is null. Trying to access the value will cause an error since `value` is a property on a null object.

Simply use the console debugger and you will see this yourself

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that anything has been checked at all.

The error occurs because, since nothing is checked, your querySelector is returning null.

```
var checkedThingy = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked');
  if (!checkedThingy) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Please select your gender";
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n516njaw/

Answer (score 0):

If the value is not checked then it is false.

So you need to check all radio buttons, and if all are false then suggest select gender.

```js
function myGender() {
  /* gender=document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value; */
  //if (document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value==null) {
  if ( ![].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[name="gender"]')).reduce(function(p,input) { p = p || input.checked; return p; },'') ) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Please select your gender";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
      <label for="gender"> Gender: </label> <br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="man"> man<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="woman" >woman<br>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" >Other<br>
      <button onclick="myGender()">What am I?</button>
     <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```